# How to move the aws S3 file from one folder to another folder in same bucket using Java? Getting Null pointer exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

While am copying object from source to destination, I am getting `Null pointer exception`. Please find the code snippet.

```
public void moveFile(String filePath, String destinationPath) {
        AmazonS3URI source = new AmazonS3URI(filePath);
        AmazonS3URI destination = new AmazonS3URI(destinationPath);
        
        CopyObjectResult copyObject = s3Client.copyObject(source.getBucket(),
                  source.getKey(), destination.getBucket(), destination.getKey());
```

On the **copy object** variable am getting `Null pointer exception`.

The requirement is that I want to move the file from source to destination in S3 bucket using AWS Lambda function.

Comment: What are the values of `source.getBucket(), source.getKey(), destination.getBucket(), destination.getKey()`?

Comment: The values is correct, when am using AmazonS3 copyObject method and passing the argument source.getBucket(), source.getKey(), destination.getBucket(), destination.getKey(), the copyObject is not loading with values.

bucket-> abd2020
Key-> Inbound/textFile.csv
DestBucket-> abd2020(Same bucket)
destKey->Archive/testFile.csv

Comment: The error message suggests that those values are _not_ correct.

Comment: The source: grrps-devsourceKey :Inbound/TEST_LOBLevelPG_Weekly_SGRRPS_20200330000002_1of1.csv
The Destination: grrps-devDestinationKey :Archive/TEST_LOBLevelPG_Weekly_SGRRPS_20200330000002_1of1.csv
The coyp object:null
The copyObject vatiable:null
Jul 17, 2020 3:59:19 PM com.irx.sgrrps.lambda.FileHandler handleRequest

Comment: SEVERE: Loader Exception: S3 Error : Not Able to copy file s3://grrps-dev/Inbound/TEST_LOBLevelPG_Weekly_SGRRPS_20200330000002_1of1.csv to s3://grrps-dev/Archive/TEST_LOBLevelPG_Weekly_SGRRPS_20200330000002_1of1.csv (Service: null; Status Code: 0; Error Code: null; Request ID: null; S3 Extended Request ID: null; Proxy: null)
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: S3 Error : Not Able to copy file

Comment: I suggest you try hard-coding the values to check whether it is working correctly (`CopyObjectResult copyObject = s3Client.copyObject('abd2020', 'Inbound/textFile.csv', 'abd2020', 'Archive/testFile.csv');`). Depending upon whether that works, you can try to determine why you are getting the error. For example, it is possible that you have not correctly defined `s3Client`.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, i tried with hard-coded values as well. After declaring the hard-coded values also am getting NPE. 
Code snip
=======
CopyObjectRequest copyObject=new CopyObjectRequest(source.getBucket(),
      source.getKey(), destination.getBucket(), destination.getKey());
CopyObjectResult copyObjectResult = s3.copyObject(copyObject);--> Getting null at this line

Comment: If all those values are correct, then it suggests that the problem is with your `s3` object.